# How to fix FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions in React Hook?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, next-auth

I am using a combination of React Hook, Next.js, and Firebase Auth to create a user coin record in Firestore. This means that as soon as a new user signs up, a new document with a `uid` should be automatically created for them in Firestore, along with the `coins` and `createdAt` fields.

However, when I sign in for the first time, I encounter an error message that says:

> hydration-error-info.js:27 Error in createUserCoinRecord: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions."

However, if I log out and sign in again, the error does not occur anymore.

Upon checking the Firebase database, I noticed that the `uid` for the user is not created after the first sign-in but is only created after the second sign-in.

Here's the code for the React Hook:

```js
export function useCoinRecord() {
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  const userEmailRef = useRef(null);
  const [created, setCreated] = useState(false);

  async function createUserCoinRecord(uid) {
    await setDoc(doc(db, "users", uid), {
      coins: 100000,
      createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    async function createCoinRecordIfNeeded() {
      if (session) {
        if (userEmailRef.current !== session.user.email) {
          userEmailRef.current = session.user.email;
          try {
            await createUserCoinRecord(session.user.email);
            setCreated(true);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error in createUserCoinRecord:", error);
          }
        }
      } else {
        userEmailRef.current = null;
      }
    }

    createCoinRecordIfNeeded();
  }, [session]);

  return { created };
}
```

And these are my Firestore rules:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{uid} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
    match /users/{uid}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
  }
}
```

The Sign in button:

```js
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";
//...
      <button onClick={() => signIn("google")}>
        Sign In
      </button>
```

Sign in with Next Auth:

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

Then use `useEffect` to sign in with Firebase:

```js
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { auth, db } from "../firebase/firebase";
//...

  const { data: session } = useSession();
  const { coinBalance, setCoinBalance } = useCoinBalanceContext();
  const [readyToFetchBalance, setReadyToFetchBalance] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (session) {
      signInWithFirebase(session).then((uid) => {
        if (uid) {
          setReadyToFetchBalance(true);
        }
      });
    }
  }, [session]);

  const signInWithFirebase = async (session) => {
    const response = await fetch("/api/firebase/create-custom-token", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ user: session.user }),
    });

    const customToken = await response.json();

    return signInWithCustomToken(auth, customToken.token)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        return userCredential.user.uid;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Firebase sign-in error:", error);
      });
  };

  const { created } = useCoinRecord();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (readyToFetchBalance && created && session?.user?.email) {
      (async () => {
        const balance = await getCoinBalance(session.user.email);
        balance && setCoinBalance(balance);
      })();
    }
  }, [session, readyToFetchBalance, created]);
```

`/api/firebase/create-custom-token`

```js
import { adminAuth } from "@/firebase/firebaseAdmin";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method !== "POST") {
    res.status(405).json({ message: "Method not allowed" });
    return;
  }

  const { user } = req.body;

  const uid = user.email;

  try {
    const customToken = await adminAuth.createCustomToken(uid);

    res.status(200).json({ token: customToken });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error creating custom token:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Error creating custom token" });
  }
}
```

`firebase.js`

```js
import { getApp, getApps, initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_APIKEY,
authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN,
databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASEURL,
projectId: process.env.PROJECTID,
storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET,
messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APPID,
measurementId: process.env.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENTID,
};

const app = getApps().length ? getApp() : initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const auth = getAuth(app);
export { db, auth };
```

`firebaseAdmin.js`

```js
import admin from "firebase-admin";

const serviceAccount = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY);
if (!admin.apps.length) {
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  });
}

const adminDb = admin.firestore();
const adminAuth = admin.auth();

export { adminDb, adminAuth };
```

My database is structured like this:

```
/users/email@example.com/coins
```

where `email@example.com` is the `uid`.

What could be causing the FirebaseError and how can I fix it please?

Comment: Maybe this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404) will help.

Comment: The `request.auth` is automatically populated when you sign the user with Firebase Authentication by callign one of the `signInWith...` functions, but none of the code you shared does that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you, Frank. I've added more files. And thanks for the link, Alex.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've added more context to this: when I sign in for the first time, I encounter the error. However, if I log out and sign in again, the error does not occur anymore. Upon checking the Firebase database, I noticed that the `uid` for the user is not created after the first sign-in but is only created after the second sign-in.

Comment: I found the problem and posted the solution. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that there is a race between two hooks that are running at the same time.

The issue is that `useCoinRecord()` tries to create a new document before the user is authenticated. To fix this, I removed `useCoinRecord()` and modified the `useEffect()` hook to include the necessary logic for creating the user coin record before setting the `ReadyToFetchBalance` flag to true.

The updated code looks like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (session) {
    signInWithFirebase(session).then(async (uid) => {
      if (uid) {
        await createUserCoinRecord(uid);
        setReadyToFetchBalance(true);
      }
    });
  }
}, [session]);
```

This should solve the race condition problem and ensure that the document is only created after the user is authenticated.